# Simple terminology question about the Dubrovnik (Kauffman) polynomial

Tags: gn.general-topology, knot-theory

In my S matrix classification attempts I encounter a lot of
Dubrovnik polynomials of the form D(z-1/z,z^n) and D(-z+1/z,z^n). 
[Second variable is for writhe, n is an integer; for the first I don't 
relate to the skein relation because having a 50:50 chance of sign, 
I will in 100% choose the false :-)]

Anyway, the one I seek has n=1 and is very easily to describe:
All knots evaluate to 1. (Still, e.g. it can detect the mirrors
of 6_3_3, the smallest nonalternating link.) Some more values:
unlink 2, Hopf z^2+1/z^2, 421 z^4+1/z^4, Whitehead 2

I wouldn't wonder if this specialization of the Dubrovnik polynomial 
(it's the "other" solution for dimension 2 S matrices besides the Jones)
already has a special name. Does it?

Comment: This is probably one of the families SO(2n+1), SO(2n), SP(2n), or OSP(1|2n).  Figuring out which requires chasing through a bunch of conventions, but if you look at the background to our paper (with Scott and Emily) http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0022 you should be able to sort it out.  In particular look at page 7 for our conventions for Dubrovnik and the bottom of page 9 for the specializations giving those families.

Comment: Close enough. (Identified, but not "specially named".)
The paper even answers some questions I didn't ask yet :-)

Comment: Right, basically they only get special names if they were discovered and named prior to Reshetikhin-Turaev's work.  Anyway which of those families did it turn out to be?  I commented instead of answering just because I didn't know which one was the right answer, but it'd be good to actually have an answer posted.